# Scifi comedy about guy who removes dreams from people's minds by downloading them into his memory

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone know a Scifi comedy book about guy who removes dreams from people's minds by downloading them into his memory? Seems like it was written early 2000s and I recall it having a lot of random funny things reminiscent of Douglas Adams books.

Comment: Perhaps Neil Gaiman's Sandman graphic stories?   Morpheus walks through others' dreams...